# Copy a dynamically generated PHP Web page to Word 2010 with Diagrams

Tags: ms-word

I am creating a PHP generated report page (using a back-end DB for values), which contains images. This page is then copied and pasted to MS Word, where I run a few macros on it to generate some figures.

I used to use MS Word 2003 earlier and there was no problem with the copy of the page and images, but when I upgraded to MS Word 2010, the images do not get copied.

The PHP page is password protected and uses HTTPS, where I have to enter a Username and Password for the final report page to be displayed. In Word 2003, the user dialog used to appear, but it does not do the same for Word 2010.

Is there some setting in Word 2010, which I need to enable for the images to be shown and/or the user/password dialog prompt to appear?

Answer (score 0):

One way which I have found is to copy the content to a New Outlook message window. This way all the images and text comes up, then copy from there onto the MS Word document. Not sure how  and why, but both the images and text show up there, although the alignment is a bit skewed.

(I even tried un-checking the box for "Show Image Placeholders" in the Advance options of MS Word 2010, but still no effect.)